# How do you get all the urls of images attached to a post?

Tags: posts, urls, xml

I've searched high and low and can't seem to get it.

I'm trying to output an XML feed with all the images attached to a post from a custom post type:

```
</BasicDetails>
<Pictures>
 <Picture>
  <PictureUrl><?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?></PictureUrl>
 <Caption></Caption>
 </Picture><Picture>
 <PictureUrl></PictureUrl>
 <Caption></Caption>
</Picture>
</Pictures>
```

I'm using wp_get_attachment_url but it's only returning one image (There's more than one per post)

```
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
```

The `<Picture>` is a repeating element so it should start an new tree when there's another image attached.

Any help would be Amazing!

Comment: So do you want all images for a single post in a custom post type, or all images for all posts of a custom post type?

Comment: All the image urls from a post. The feed is outputting all the posts from a custom post type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop through the attachments within your post loop, replace the section of code you posted with this (put this together from [some other code I found](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-all-images-attached-to-a-post-based-on-gallery) related to a similar problem, but couldn't test it):

```
</BasicDetails>
<?php  $args = array(
            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'numberposts'    => -1, // show all
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
            'order'           => 'ASC'
       );

$images = get_posts($args);
if($images) { ?>
<Pictures>
  <?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
   <Picture>
    <PictureUrl><?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID); ?></PictureUrl>
     <Caption><?php echo $image->post_excerpt; ?></Caption>
  </Picture>
  <?php } ?>
</Pictures>
<?php } ?>
<Agent>
```

EDIT - Updated based on asker edits.

Comment: Will test it now, is the last tag open? and `}` necessary?

Comment: @Marco assuming some kind of php code immediately follows this piece of code the last tag should be open yes, if you are echoing out more tags you can just stick a `?>` on the end.  So it will be either as posted `<?php }` or `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Gotcha, though I added the above `if(` statement in function.php and it crashed my site. I should of mentioned that I was using a commercial theme which is heavily customized.

Comment: @Marco can you update the question with the whole section of functions.php relating to this and any front end code.

Comment: I updated my question with the XML file that I'm using.

Comment: @Marco I have updated the solution and supplied a bit of context to the beginning and end of the code block, let me know how you get on.  If it goes to white screen again can you turn on wp_debug in wp-config.php and check what error it is giving?

Comment: will try it as soon as my server comes back up (Unrelated but don't use bluehost)

Comment: Wonderful!! If your were in NYC I'd buy you a beer. I do have one more issue, the post_per_page for some strange reason is capping at 45. When I put `-1` I get a parse error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Marco I wish! Well you could try adding `nopaging => true,` to your posts query arguments near the top.

Comment: haha, well if you ever are let me know! nopaging didn't seem to work. Maybe I should start a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21558/discussion-between-jason-murray-and-marco).

Answer (score 3):

use this code in the post loop.

```
$attimages = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
foreach ($attimages as $image) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID).'<br>';
}
```

this code will return all attached images url